Running a python program from a terminal on Mac OS
I’m studying python crash course 2nd edition by Eric Matthes. On pg 12 it states to run a program from the terminal in order to run hello_world.py
The first line of code is
~$ cd Desktop/python_work/
But when I type that in and hit enter I get a syntax error saying the character $ is invalid. I’m not sure where to go from here. I could skip and move on but I want to learn it correctly
I tried leaving out the character $ but I get more errors so it’s needed in the line of code but then I receive an error. I’ve looked online and YouTube. No luck

Long story short, you need to customize that command a little to make it work for your specific use case. This Wikipedia article might be of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)

Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [apple.se] for really basic command-line literacy questions, but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

If you're getting an error because of the $ character, it's likely because you're trying to type it as part of your command. The $ character is not meant to be typed; it's just a symbol used in the book to represent the command prompt in the terminal or command line.
Don't type the $ when you're entering commands.
Here's how you can proceed:
cd Desktop/python_work/

python hello_world.py


I tried that then it tells me Desktop is invalid

The command assumes that you are in your home directory (type cd at the prompt to get there) and that you have a directory named Desktop and a (presumably newly created) directory python_work in your Desktop.

If you get an error saying Desktop is invalid, it might be because the path or folder does not exist. Here’s how to check
To understand where you are starting from, type:
pwd

This command prints the current working directory.
Navigating to the Desktop:
You can navigate directly using:
cd ~/Desktop/python_work


The ~ symbol represents your home directory. Ensure that the folder python_work exists on your Desktop.

Verify the Folder:
Make sure python_work exists on your Desktop. If it doesn’t:
create it with:
mkdir ~/Desktop/python_work

Once in the correct directory, run your Python script```
